# How to make the type of parameters consistent while using decorator pattern in Typescript

Tags: typescript, decorator

I have several functions that need to access a DB.

```js
const dbProcess1 = (s1: string) => {
    console.log(`dbProcess1 is called with a param : ${s1}`)
};

const dbProcess2 = (s2: string, n2: number) => {
    console.log(`dbProcess2 is called with params : ${s2}, ${n2}`)
};

const dbProcess3 = (s1: string, s2: string, n2: number) => {
    dbProcess1(s1);
    dbProcess2(s2, n2);
};
```

I want to control a spinner before and after these process.
The following decorator is my approach.

```js
const withSpinner = (process: (...params: any[]) => void) => {
    return (...params: any[]) => {
        console.log('display spinner');
        process(...params);
        console.log('stop spinner');
    }
};

const dbProcess1WithSpinner = withSpinner(dbProcess1);
const dbProcess2WithSpinner = withSpinner(dbProcess2);
const dbProcess3WithSpinner = withSpinner(dbProcess3);

dbProcess1WithSpinner('p1');
dbProcess2WithSpinner('p2','42');
dbProcess3WithSpinner('p1', 'p2', '42');
```

However, this approach make the type hint useless:

```js
const dbProcess3: (s1: string, s2: string, n2: number) => void
```

becomes

```js
const dbProcess3WithSpinner: (...params: any[]) => void
```

Any suggestions to make it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the typings with a bit of generics:

```
declare function dbProcess3(s1: string, s2: string, n2: number): void;

const withSpinner = <T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(process: T) => {
    return (...params: Parameters<T>) => {
        console.log('display spinner');
        process(...params);
        console.log('stop spinner');
    }
};

const dbProcess3WithSpinner = withSpinner(dbProcess3); // is now (s1: string, s2: string, n2: number) => void

dbProcess3WithSpinner('p1', 'p2', '42'); // error: Argument of type '"42"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'
```

Now decorator params are properly type checked (it will only accept the same set of parameters as a decorated function expects to get).

Function parameters type is extracted with [Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterst) utility

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtX2ACMAFGHMEAZ0oGYAKSgRgC55KMYtUBzAGjYBMrdpx79UQ+KmQBbQiBgBKVgDccWYAG4AsACg9YPO3gB3LBgAWAZQAOXVAvgBeeAB4AKvBAAPDCFTAlPB0AHRhsNyUrFCoAJ4A2gC6is4AfPAxsal0NmQU1KzuKU7pAN568JXwcBjIMPihYTawUDJR8MQtMiB+MJQeqcVlFVWjhqiUOBAgIRA43HQA5MBYlDbQsWx2qA4wi4o6uqOjueRUlI0hzTCtlAcjx-Djk9Oz80vsODZb9gr7h6MAL56QGHAxGDAEEh5c40ADq5ms212zlMiNsvxgdCIpDO1BoB3gAHoifBVlIcCZgkxhBwuHxBLTRAyJKxpHIFEN4GoNHo9DiYfiEZYMTsFEsbIxFvxFjYBNL4IsACzywkkrwwMgwVgAQRg3Fk-khOEQ8AwsRsCEWACIVdbFmSgqgcJCoNQsNxUFBCNMzTh4NdWj1HCazRarez5HsgA)